# Условие наличия галочки (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку в C#. Есть колонка CheckBoxColumn, в цикле пробегаю по строкам в DataGridView, как можно сделать создать условие, при котором если в CheckBoxColumn стоит галочка, то учитывать, если не стоит, то пропускать.

Comment: if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].EditedFormattedValue)
                    {
                        
                        //действия;
                    }
                    else
                    {
}
где j номер столбца с CheckBoxColumn

Answer (score 2):

```
if (CheckBoxColumn.checked)
{
    // Галочка в стоит
}
```